# The iterator doesn't iterate over the entire map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, iterator

I have the following function:

```
   void send_sequence_to_device( std::map<const string_t,device_t*> &msg2device_p, std::vector<response_t>& result_list, ushort num_attempts)
    {
        cout<<"sarit enter to send_seq_device"<<endl;
        std::map<const string_t, device_t*>::iterator msg_itf;
        for( msg_itf=msg2device_p.begin(); msg_itf!=msg2device_p.end(); msg_itf++ )
        {
            cout<<"sarit enter to seq "<<msg_itf->first<<endl;
        }
    }
```

I call this function by another function:

```
 void node_layer_manager_t::calc_ts_job_function()
    {
        vector<response_t> res;
        map<const string_t, device_t*> getRegMsg={{"get_node_ts_est",&tx},{"get_node_ts_est",&rx},{"get_tx_num_clk_ts",&tx}};
        cout<< "sarit ts clk function nlm first"<<endl;
        send_sequence_to_device(getRegMsg,res);
    }
```

i can see that the loop iterate only 2 instead of 3.
The output is:

```
sarit enter to seq get_node_ts_est

sarit enter to get_tx_num_clk_ts
```

While I expect for:

```
sarit enter to seq get_node_ts_est

sarit enter to seq get_node_ts_est

sarit enter to get_tx_num_clk_ts
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `setRegMsg` (which is what you're passing to your `send_sequence_to_device()` function)?

Comment: Do you know what [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) is for?

Answer (score 5):

A `std::map` does not allow duplicate keys.

Two of your values have the same key, hence only one of them will make it into the map.

Use `std::multimap` instead of `std::map`, if you need duplicate keys.